# Как правильно освободить память занятую элементами vector

Tags: c++, vector

Не могли бы пожалуйста подсказать, при добавление элемента в вектор я создаю его с помощью команды new

```
void Company::makeOrder(const char* name, const float price)
{
    Order* new_order = new Order(name, price);
    orders_.push_back(new_order);
}
```

И в конце программы я хочу чтобы деструктор класса, который хранит в себе vector удалил все его элементы, и если честно не получается, может кто подскажет?

```
class Order;

class Company
{
  public:
  Company(std::string name);
  virtual ~Company()
  {
    auto new_it = orders_.end();
    for(auto it = orders_.begin(); it != new_it; it++)
    {
        delete  OrderVector[*it];
    }
  }

  void makeOrder(const char* name, const float price);
  void removeOrdersByProductName(const char* name);


  void hire(const Employee& employee);
  void fire(const char* name);
  void renameEmployee(const char* old_name, const char* new_name);

  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Company& company);

private:
  std::string name_;

  typedef std::list<Employee> EmployeeList;
  EmployeeList employees_;

  typedef std::vector<Order*> OrderVector;
  OrderVector orders_;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Company& company);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Данное предложение

```
delete  OrderVector[*it];
```

не имеет смысла. `OrderVector` - это имя типа. Поэтому применять к нему оператор индексирования бессмысленно.

Все можно сделать без всякого написания вручную цикла с помощью стандартного алгоритма `std::for_each` и стандартного функционального объекта `std::default_delete`.

Вот демонстрационная программа.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>

struct Order
{
    ~Order() { std::cout << "Order::~Order()" << std::endl; }
};  

typedef std::vector<Order*> OrderVector;

int main() 
{
    OrderVector orders = { new Order(), new Order(), new Order() };

    std::for_each( orders.begin(), orders.end(), std::default_delete<Order>() );

    return 0;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль

```
Order::~Order()
Order::~Order()
Order::~Order()
```

Если хотите использовать цикл вместо алгоритма, то достаточно написать

```
for ( auto order : orders ) delete order;
```

Например,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Order
{
    ~Order() { std::cout << "Order::~Order()" << std::endl; }
};  

typedef std::vector<Order*> OrderVector;

int main() 
{
    OrderVector orders = { new Order(), new Order(), new Order() };

    for ( auto order : orders ) delete order;

    return 0;
}
```

Результат будет такой же, что и для программы, показанной выше.

Что касается вашего собственного цикла, то правильно его будет записать следующим образом:

```
for ( auto it = orders_.begin(); it != orders_.end(); ++it )
{
    delete *it;
}
```

Обратите внимание, что вместо данного объявления конструктора

```
Company(std::string name);
```

будет лучше записать

```
Company( const std::string &name );
```

Также в виду того, что вы используете вектор указателей, вам следует либо запретить копирование объектов класса, как, например, в определении класса записать

```
Company( const Company & ) = delete;
Company & operator =( const Company & ) = delete;
```

Либо определить их явно.

Comment: Комплиятор ругается на std::default_delete

Comment: Company.h: In destructor ‘virtual Company::~Company()’:
Company.h:26:13: error: ‘default_delete’ is not a member of ‘std’
std::default_delete<Order>();
^
Company.h:26:38: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
std::default_delete<Order>();
^
Company.h:26:40: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
std::default_delete<Order>();

Comment: @AntonBarinov Вы должны включить заголовок <memory>, где определен функциональный  объект std::default_delete, Если ваш компилятор не поддерживает этл средство, то используйте цикл for на основе диапазона. как я показал. В крайнем случае можете использовать исправленный ваш цикл.:)

Comment: Понял, спасибо, попробую обязательно ! :)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Спасибо за std::default_delete, что-то я его не замечал раньше.

Comment: @Cerbo Теперь запомните.:) Он используется по умолчанию в определении std::unique_ptr

Answer (score 3):

Если вы хотите чтобы при удалении элементов автоматически выполнялся их деструктор, то вам нужно либо завернуть указатели в "умные указатели", либо хранить в векторе не указатели, а сами объекты.

Для первого варианта можно (и нужно!) использовать `std::shared_ptr`. Однако в этом случае деструктор `Order` будет вызываться не обязательно когда удаляется вектор. Он будет вызываться когда удалится последний умный указатель на его объект:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

typedef std::shared_ptr<Order   > OrderPtr    ;
typedef std::vector    <OrderPtr> OrderVector;

OrderVector orders_;

void Company::makeOrder(const char* name, const float price)
{
    // безопасно создаем умный указатель
    auto new_order = std::make_shared<Order>(name, price); 
    orders_.push_back(new_order);
}
```

Второй вариант, деструктор вектора автоматически вызовет деструкторы для каждого элемента:

```
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<Order> OrderVector;

OrderVector orders_;

void Company::makeOrder(const char* name, const float price)
{
    auto new_order = Order(name, price); 
    orders_.push_back(new_order);        
}

// а лучше так
void Company::emplaceOrder(const char* name, const float price)
{
    orders_.emplace_back(name, price);        
}
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, я почитаю и постараюсь разобраться с умными указателями

Answer (score 2):

Может, просто `delete *it`? :)

Вам же надо удалять, передавая указатель, который хранится в элементе...

Ваше `OrderVector[*it]` - это указатель, который хранится в векторе в элементе с номером, который представляет собой хранящийся в текущем элементе указатель, рассмотренный как целочисленное значение, т.е. с вероятностью 99.9999% фиг знает что, а не реальный указатель...

P.S. Меня поправили - да, я не обратил внимания, что `OrderVector` - тип, а не вектор; мои пояснения относились к `OrderVector`, если бы это был вектор...

Comment: Спасибо, попробуй запустить её в valgrind, посмотреть

Comment: `OrderVector` в коде автора - это имя типа. Поэтому `OrderVector[*it]` - это вообще некорректная бессмыслица.

Comment: @AnT Да, даже не обратил внимания. *Такого* я просто не ожидал :)

Answer (score 2):

Что такое `delete  OrderVector[*it];`???

Вам нужно просто в цикле сделать

```
delete *it;
```

Однако имейте в виду, что если с вектором такой номер еще пройдет, то вот с другим типом контейнера запросто могут возникнуть проблемы.

Контейнеры с более сложной структурой (`set`, `unordered_map` и т.п.) могут требовать того, чтобы все элементы контейнера содержали корректные значения во все моменты времени. Разрушать содержимое элемента контейнера в них можно только вместе с удалением (и только после удаления) самого элемента из контейнера.

В том числе именно по этой причине имеет смысл использовать "умные указатели" для хранения указателей в контейнерах.